# scrapy module path difference when running via script or terminal

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy spider that imports a dictionary from another module. My main contentspider.py that contains the spider also contains an import statement `from spider_project.spider_project.updated_kw import translated_kw_dicts`.

```
from spider_project.spider_project.updated_kw import translated_kw_dicts

class ContentSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'content_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print(traslated_kw_dicts)
```

This import statement works fine when the spider is running as a script, but when I run it via conda then I get an error:

```
spider_project.spider_project.updated_kw import translated_kw_dicts
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spider_project.spider_project'
```

From conda I am running the spider as it should be - from the directory containing .cfg file: `c:/.../.../spider_project`
If I will change the import statement to `from spider_project.updated_kw import translated_kw_dicts` (notice I'm taking out the first spider_project directry) then via conda the spider runs fine, but I get an error `Cannot find reference 'updated_kw' in 'imported module spider_project'` in my script.

Can someone advise why this is happening?
Here is my project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when you click on the long line up in the file explorer then it should go active. You can copie it and use the fail reading technic.